# Do slippers and slides (sliders) mean the same thing?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I wanted to know if slippers and slides mean the same thing, so I did a search and [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqGuF.jpg) is what I found. It doesn't really say if they are one and the same.

> Are slides and slippers the same thing?
>
> ---
>
> A slide, also known as a slide sandal, is a backless, open-toed shoe that gets its name from being easy to slide on and off the foot. ... The slide is a type of sandal, but not all sandals are slides. For example, flip flops might be easy to slip on, but they aren't slides.
>
> [Shoe Glossary: Slide - LiveAbout](https://www.liveabout.com/what-are-shoe-slides-and-slide-sandals-2987860)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slippers are soft, non-laced shoes for indoor use, usually without socks. Because they are unlaced they slip on. Shoes for outdoor use may be unlaced, eg slip-on shoes may have strong elastic holding them so that they grip the foot, but they are not slippers.

Sandals are usually intended for outdoor use, and the design provides protection to the sole and allows air flow to cool the feet. Slippers are usually designed to keep the feet warm in an environment where the soles need little protection.

Comment: I (UK) have never heard the term _slide_ or _slider_ for footwear - I would call them _slip-on sandals_. Maybe it's a term used in the shoe trade.

Comment: @KateBunting I (Australia) have come across the term before, but not in actual use. Perhaps it is US.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations !